# ffpmeg extracting frames produces too many images

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFMpeg to extract some png files from a video using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i FILE.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,75))" -vsync vfr img_%03d.png
```

the source video has a duration of 2898 seconds and a framerate of 25 FPS.  This means I should be grabbing a picture every 3 seconds for 966 pictures.

However, instead I'm getting 1158 pictures.  After doing some math I've discovered that that is the within 2 pictures of what I would expect if I was grabbing the 75th frame from a 30 FPS video.

I've tried -framerate=25 but it still produces the same amount of pictures.  The video does have a variable framerate, however using ffprobe it says that the max FPS is 25.47.  So even if it was at the max FPS the whole video then I'd still only expect to see 984 pictures.

Is there anyway to tell FFMpeg that my source video is only 25 fps?  Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you want to extract a frame every three seconds why don't you use `select=not(mod(t\,3))`?

Comment: because I wasn't aware of that option :)

Comment: hmm... using the t\ option results in an error message reading Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Comment: `ffmpeg -i FILE.mp4 -vf 'select=not(mod(t\,3))' -vsync vfr img_%03d.png` with this command, I can't reproduce that error

Comment: I just tried it again by copy and pasting your code and got a message saying `No such filter: 'select=not(mod(t\,3))'`. I'm on Windows 10 using ffmpeg x64 version N-94664-g0821bc4eee that I downloaded earlier this week.  It might also be an issue with the way this specific video was encoded?

Comment: I don't think so. But also I don't have Windows on my PC so I can't try it, sorry

Comment: I just opened the video up in vlc and it's claiming the framerate IS 30 fps.  I'm trying to figure out which one is correct. I'm leaning towards ffmpeg/vlc

Comment: Okay turns out there's something messed up with the video's metadata information.  When I take a look at the calculated r_frame_rate it is saying it's 30 FPS.  Everything is actually working as expected.